# SQL Newbie - Over Partition?

Tags: sql-server, partition

I have the following query. I am trying to get the Row # to increment whenever the value in Value1 field changes. The `SensorData` table has 2800 records and the `Value1` is either 0 or 3 and changes throughout the day.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Value1 ORDER BY Block ASC) AS Row#,
    GatewayDetailID, Block, Value1
FROM            
    SensorData
ORDER BY
    Row#
```

I get the following results:

[image]

It seems like it creates only 2 partitions 0 and 3. It is not restarting the row number every time the value 1 changes.?

Comment: Can you explicitly specify what kind of output is required ? that would help you to get your query resolved quickly.

Comment: You are searching for kind of gaps-and-islands solution. Easiest way is to use subgrouping with windowed SUM and then use the row_number partitioned by this subgroup. Please provide sample data in form of http://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: I want to sort the entire record set by time ASC and have the row number restart at 1 whenever value1 changes

Comment: Here is the data sctucture and sample data

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IOTSensorData](
 [GUID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [GatewayDetailID] [int] NULL,
 [Block] [datetime] NULL,
 [Value1] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 [Value2] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 [Vaule3] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: The `PARTITION BY` creates "partitions" (groups) of data - here, there's one partition for each vlaue of `Value1` - one for `Value1=0`, another for `Value1=1` etc. Within each of these partitions, the rows are numbered sequentially, as defined by the `ORDER BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER()`  function. So **no**, the "sequential numbering" doesn't restart at 0 with every "change" of a value - it is sequential **within each partition**

Comment: From my understanding that would be the case if the Order by was Value1 i.e.                                   OVER(PARTITION BY Value1 ORDER BY Value1 ASC)                                           But I am using                                                                        
OVER(PARTITION BY Value1 ORDER BY Block ASC) I was under the impression this would sort by the Block (timestamp) first and then partition by Value1?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - Hello Lukasz - Sorry I couldn't figure out how to use dbfiddle. I have a SQL script but its too long to paste in the comments text box. Is there an easy way to send you the script?

Comment: Just put your code into fiddle and share link like I did [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1a50c2dea88f10447f17abb1c6b12e5) with the same 15rows from your image. I really do not need the entire huge table but representative sample that corresponds to your image :)

Comment: Hi @LukaszSzozda will this work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8bbaad3679b2f2d23bb64a19c24d9bac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First instead of creating a permanent table I just changed it to a Temp table.

So, Given your example here is what I came up with:

```
WITH CTE as(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BLOCK) RN, LAG(Value1,1,VALUE1) OVER (ORDER BY BLOCK) LG, 
GatewayDetailID, Block, Value1,Value2,Vaule3
 from #tmp
), 
CTE2 as (
    select *, CASE WHEN LG <> VALUE1 THEN RN ELSE 0 END RowMark 
    from cte
    ), 
CTE3 AS (
    select MIN(Block) BL, RowMark from CTE2
    GROUP BY ROwMark
    ),
CTE4 AS (
    SELECT GatewayDetailID,Block,Value1,Value2,Vaule3,RMM from cte2 t1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(ROWMark) RMM FROM CTE3 t9 where t1.Block >= t9.ROwMark and t1.RN >= t9.RowMark) t2
    )

SELECT GateWayDetailID,Block,Value1,Value2,Vaule3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by RMM ORDER BY BLOCK) RN
FROM CTE4
ORDER BY BLOCK
```

I first had to get a Row number for all the rows, then depending on when the Value1 changed I marked that as a new group.  From that I created a CTE with the date and row boundry for each group.  And then lastly I cross applied that back to the table to find each row in each group.

From that last CTE I merely just applied a simple ROW_NUMBER() function portioned by each RowMarker group and poof....row numbers.

There may be a better way to do this, but this was how I logically worked through the problem.

Comment: Wow! Thanks JM - exactly what I was looking for -thanks so much.

Comment: Go ahead and mark this as complete if it answers your question.  Glad it helped!